# Regex_match for particular character of given string c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the match the characters of a string(s) to a specific set of characters ("aeiou").

Once matched, I intend to reverse the order of the vowels.

I get an error for matching function for regex_match(). Not sure if I can pass a character as an argument for a regex_match?

EDIT:
    ERROR: no matching function for call to 'regex_match(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type&, std::__cxx11::regex&)'

This is what my code looks like:

```
string reverseVowels(string s) {

    vector<int> v;
    std::regex r("[aeiou]");

    for (int i=0;i<s.length();j++)       //find all vowels and push back to vector
    {
        if (std::regex_match(s[i],r)))
        {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for (int j=0;j<v.size()/2;j++)      //swap first and last element
    {
        char temp=s[v[j]];
        s[v[i]]=s[v[v.size()-1]];
        s[v[v.size()-1-j]]=temp;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: *"Not sure if I can pass a character as an argument for a regex_match?"* - what reference documentation are you using?

Comment: ERROR:  no matching function for call to 'regex_match(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&, std::__cxx11::regex&)'

Comment: No you can't put a char there, look at documentation... Also, why not just make a function that checks if the char is a vowel??

Comment: Reference: cplusplus.com,cppreference.com

Comment: @-Pat-Laugh: I could make a function. (using either switch, or if =='a','e','i','o','u') but wanted to see if i could use regex_match

Comment: Please, accept my answer if it was satisfactory and helped you, else, tell me how can I help you more!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter mentioned in the `regex_match()` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) is a string, you've got send a string, otherwise, warnings or errors could be generated and even if they don't show up, you can't expect it to work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

std::string reverseVowels(std::string s) {

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::regex r("[aeiou]");

    for (uint i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        std::string single = s.substr(i, 1);

        if (std::regex_match(single, r)) {

            v.push_back(i);

        }

    }

    for (uint j = 0; j < (v.size()/2); j++) {

        char ch = s[v[j]];

        s[v[j]] = s[v[v.size()-j-1]];
        s[v[v.size()-j-1]] = ch;

    }

    return s;
}

int main() {

    std::cout << reverseVowels("Mateus");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As were stated in the comments, `regex_match` does not work on `char`. Also match is intended if you are interested if a string *matches* your regex. You seem to be interested in finding all occurrences, which can be achieved with regex iterators. Something like that:

```
for (auto i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r); i != std::sregex_iterator(); ++i) {
    v.push_back(i->position());
}
```